# How can I figure out why my Wordpress pages load so slowly?

Tags: performance, wordpress, optimization, pagespeed, yslow

Yet my site pages load very slowly. Usually there's a 2-3 second lag before the page renders, and I cannot figure out why.

- My site is powered by Wordpress v3.4.2.
- I'm on a dedicated virtual server with plenty of resources and
  bandwidth.
- There are no huge images loading.
- My CSS files load before JS scripts.

I've spent a lot of time trying to optimize the site within the constraints of the platform (Wordpress + plugins, etc). I don't expect my site to be SUPER fast, but I need it to not be SO slow.

I'm using Chrome's developer tools to audit my site but the suggestions do not appear to explain the long load time (unused CSS rules, etc). When I look at the timeline, I see a 2.7x second load time initially but I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

My site is located [here](http://streetofwalls.com). The homepage has some extra scripts, so it may be more helpful to look at [this page](http://streetofwalls.com/about-us).

Comment: If you are not caching or using other WP specific optimization on the server it seems to be running OK for me on OS X. One thing, there are too many scripts being called. Maybe there is a way to combine those. Also, consider a WP specific host such as Page.ly or WPEngine

Comment: You aren't specifying sensible cashing defaults or marshalling your css and js into unified resources.  There is also about a 1.5s lag on your main doc html starting to stream back to the browser.  Have you also sorted out the obvious stuff like making sure that you are using mod_php5 instead of cgi and also an opcode cache such as APC or xcache?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the 1.5s lag? I see that also in the tools I'm using but I don't know what causes it. Is that a server issue?

Comment: If there is a 1.5s lag on the main doc streaming back to the browser there's a healthy chance this is caused by too many modules loading in Apache, using too much memory then memory thrashing. I had this exact same problem.

Comment: I can only observe the lag from the client-end.  I can only guess, not _investigate_, the causes.  As I hinted, WP loads ~100 PHP script files to fart. mod_php5 means you don't pay for PHP image activation (~100mSec) per request.  APC (with stat=0) means you don't go loading all that crap from your file system and instead the previously compiled code is fetched from the SHM cache.  You can also use memcached to memory cache some of WP's meta data. All basic 101 stuff.  There are lots of Q&As around this topic if you care to explore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this superb guide which really helped me fight through the mire of optimising Apache for use with WordPress:

http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/optimize-apache-wordpress/

You said you have a virtual server so chances are it's currently set up to load EVERY module - you'll find a great speed boost here if you eliminate unnecessary modules. Keep a backup of your config file in case you screw it up.

Also - use the TOP command through SSH to see how much memory PHP is using. Probably a lot currently. This will all be improved through eliminating modules as per above link. You don't mention how much memory you have on your VPS but there's a good chance your performance issues are coming from memory thrashing which will be mitigated significantly by reducing how much memory each PHP instance consumes using the link above.

Also, it matters to find out where your performance issues are actually coming from – a great little plugin called WP Tuner helps me locate performance bottlenecks. The original plugin is incompatible but someone else has written an upgrade:

http://www.wwvalue.com/tuts/tut-wp/wordpress-profiler-tuner-revised.html

That will help you identify which specific parts of the page are taking the longest to load so you will immediately find your performance bottleneck.

In addition, a cool plugin called Debug Queries is useful for tracking down performance issues although the wordpress profiler above actually does track queries too.

Finally – I can’t recommend highly enough this WordPress.org discussion on performance, and specifically on W3 Total Cache vs Super Cache (both are excellent).

It’s a fantastic read for anyone looking for split-second response times:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-super-cache-vs-w3-total-cache

I use W3 total cache on one of my sites and WP Super Cache on another. Both are great. I used both so I could learn about both. I would say use WP Super cache plus all the other tools the guy at the link above recommends if you're looking for extreme performance, but if you're looking to get immediate performance W3 total cache is more comprehensive in its initial setup.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow! So much great information. I'm going to get to work on it right away.

Comment: Just be sure and add a caching solution last, once you've solved all the other problems.

Answer (score 2):

- use caching plugin,
- put JS files at the bottom,
- try different webhost    (DB server may    be slow sometimes)
- minify css and JS,
- make fewer HTTP requests
- make sure external services (like FB and others) are not    slowing down (remove
  them and see if it helps)
- run Yslow or similar test
- try to use typekit or google font instead of cufon

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/ or a similar caching plugin?