# Wordpress website latency issue - Pingdom report attached

Tags: windows

Ive created my own website and having a few latency issues - any help would be amazing and could really help me.

The website is a wordpress based site, running on Azure on dedicated Windows 2012 box.
The attached pingdom report shows that the site goes from DNS to Server IP quickly (so no issues there, 33ms) requests the content (again 30 ms to 'connect) than waits over 2 seconds for the server to do...something.
Status is 'wait'

Ive disabled all plugins which are not nexessary, using no caching (at present until ive fixed this).

If anyone has any insight of suggestions that would be amazing.

Many thanks

James

Image  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QmzR.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [High latency on my Wordpress Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861518/high-latency-on-my-wordpress-site)

Comment: Ive checked the SQL queries and they are ok, page generation in 2 seconds. Its when i click 'show site' in wordpress from then, to the beginning of the loading is the delay. wp-admin page takes 3-4 seconds to load, however if i do domain.com/readme.html it loads instantly

Comment: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150107_AK_1424/ - This might help, its the Time to First Byte which is causing the problems, but finding it hard to isolate this problem

Comment: It doesn't seem *that* bad from where I am (.uk on a 50Mb/s link). Could you perhaps split up some of those 1920x1080 pixel images? Did you follow the [link in Dave Hilditch's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12326958/1115360) in the post I suggested your post was a duplicate of?

Comment: Based on the output from webpagetest, the slowness isnt content related i dont believe? - My front images are SVG and are tiny, so shouldnt be making the response of the server take 3-4 seconds. Using the backend (wp-admin) is the slowest of all, but should be really responsive as its not loading my actual webpage, so i believe the issue is server side - ill follow that guide and see how i get on :). thanks